# ResultSet MetaData not returning first row

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, metadata

This code returns every row apart from the first. I can't see what is wrong with it? How can i make it include the first?

```
stmt = con.createStatement();  

ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Orders ORDER BY OrderID");

if (res.next())
{
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd=res.getMetaData();
    int columnCount=rsmd.getColumnCount();
    for (int i = 1; i<= columnCount; i++) {
        columnHeading=columnHeading+"\t"+rsmd.getColumnName(i); 
    }
    System.out.println(columnHeading);
    while(res.next()) {
        for (int i= 1; i<= columnCount; i++) {                            
            System.out.print("\t"+res.getString(i));
        }
    System.out.println("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `res.next()` twice - once here:

```
if (res.next())
```

and once here:

```
while (res.next())
```

Between the `if` statement and the `while` statement, you're "looking at" the first row - but by the time you get into the `while` loop body, you're already on the second row.

The simplest fix would probably be to change:

```
while (res.next())
{
}
```

To:

```
do
{
} while (res.next());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are moving the `ResultSet` along when you call `if(res.next)`.

This means that when you enter your loop you are already one row down.

Change your loop to a do-while

```
do {

} while (res.next());
```

This will run the code *before* the first loop call to `next`.

Answer (score 0):

`res.next()` will automatically move the result set on.  You call it first in the `if` statement, and then again in the `while` statement before you print any rows out, and as you are calling it twice before you print anything out, you are missing the first row.

Change the `while` to a `do..while` and this should do as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope it will work.

```
stmt = con.createStatement();  

ResultSet res=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Orders ORDER BY OrderID");

if (res != null)
{
ResultSetMetaData rsmd=res.getMetaData();
int columnCount=rsmd.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i<= columnCount; i++) {
    columnHeading=columnHeading+"\t"+rsmd.getColumnName(i); 
}
System.out.println(columnHeading);
while(res.next()) {
    for (int i= 1; i<= columnCount; i++) {                            
        System.out.print("\t"+res.getString(i));
    }
 System.out.println("\n");
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is of ResultSet's index not starting with 0. Hence
If you haven't declared ResultSet globally then you must Write in the following way:
ResultSet res = null;
otherwise it will work.